# error calling pyqt script from qt thread of another pyqt script

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qthread, raspberry-pi2

CODE

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import PyQt4
import sys
import os
import RPi.GPIO  as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
from mmc3 import Ui_MainWindow
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Mainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("image:url(/home/pi/mmc/correct.jpg)background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:bottom left;"))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.getGPIOPress = GPIOPress()
        self.getGPIOPress.start()

class GPIOPress(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                if GPIO.input(4) == False:
                    self.main = Ui_MainWindow()
                    self.main.show()
                sleep(0.5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            GPIO.cleanup()
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Mainwindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ERROR:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python mmcCorrect.py
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
X Error: BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error) 16 Major opcode: 51 (X_SetFontPath)
Resource id:  0x133
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion  '!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

This Error always shows up when ever I pressed the IO Button, instead of showing the other script(pyqt script). and also sometimes it also produces this error:
"Fatal IO error: client killed."

Any Comments/Suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As the error message tells you (over and over again), it is not safe to create/update GUI elements outside of the GUI thread. Instead, you should emit a [custom signal](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal) from the thread and connect it to a slot in the main window.

Comment: thanks for pointing me that i need to emit it from the thread. by the way how to emit and connect with a param?